# What are faulted entities in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

What are faulted entities and what the difference between them and 'usual' entities? where can I read about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADC has some documentation on this topic:

> Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes. A fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that has not yet been fully realized, or a collection object that represents a relationship:

All objects are loaded on demand to reduce memory usage.
override -(void) awakeFromFetch/Insert and -(void) willTurnIntoFault to do custom initialization

[ADC on Faulting and Uniquing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

Comment: I like to think of faults as "ghost" and faulted objects as "concrete." The object graph i.e. the exact pattern of relationships between objects, is every bit if not more important in Core Data than the data stored in attributes. Faults place a ghost in the graph so the the integrity of the graph is maintained but you don't spend the memory to store attribute data you might not need.